# Black screen on tf2 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screen, steam

I recently installed TF2 and  when I launch the game, it gives me a black screen but sound however still works. It will not even display the Valve intro unfortunately. Any ideas on how coul i solve this?

Comment: Valve problem. Recently, it released a patch for it, see if it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forums! Here are some commands that I found others have said have worked for them:

- In terminal, run `export LANG=C; steam`

or

1. In terminal, run `export LC_NUMERIC=C`
2. Start Steam

You might also want to check out your drivers - try changing to other drivers (`Settings Manager -> Software Sources -> Additional Drivers`), and see if that works.  If you change to a different driver, and it doesn't work, I would try running either of the above commands before switching to a different driver again.

Probably the best place to post bug reports and get support for anything related to Steam for Linux is at Valve's [Steam-for-Linux Github](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux). Not trying to shove you off the Askubuntu forums, just suggesting a better place for this specific issue.

---

Sources: [Issue Report: Black screen on TF2 startup](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/1/882965737488257446/#p1)

[Issue Report: Shader generation/compilation fails in TF2 - temporary fix - proper fix WIP](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/1/882965239689221201/)

Comment: thanks, but i'm kind of a noob on ubuntu xd, do i have tu run the commands directly like this? 
inescarate@Hal-9000:~$ export LC_NUMERIC=C
or do i have to put something before?

Comment: You should be able to run them just like that.

Answer (score 1):

1. #### s3tc texture compression

   Either do `export force_s3tc_enable=true` before running steam or add `force_s3tc_enable=true` right under the `#!/bin/bash` in `/usr/bin/steam`.
2. #### Locale issues

   Either do `export LANG=C` and `export LC_NUMERIC=POSIX` before running steam or add `LANG=C` and `LC_NUMERIC=POSIX` under the `#!/bin/bash` in `/usr/bin/steam`. Apparently this has been fixed. Follow these steps:

   - Open a terminal and run:

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/bin/steam
     ```
   - Add the following lines after `#! /bin/bash`:

     ```
     export LANG=C
     export LC_NUMERIC=POSIX
     ```
   - Save (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> >> Then <kbd>Enter</kbd> >> Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
   - Launch Steam
3. #### No symlinks

   There must be no symlinks involved in getting to the SteamApps directory, or `tf2` will fail on startup. If you don't want/don't have the space for `tf2` in your home directory, just add `/opt/Steam` as another steam library or the sole steam library.
4. #### Tell tf2 not to use a joystick

   Add `-nojoy` to the launch options for `tf2`.
5. #### SELinux prevents tf2 from starting

   Run `sudo setsebool -P allow_execheap 1` in the terminal to fix this.
6. #### Windowed mode

   Add `-window`, `-sw`, `-startwindowed` or `-windowed` to the launch options.
7. #### Proprietary drivers

   Some people have had luck installing the drivers from ATI's website. Be warned though that this often causes a plethora of other issues.

---

Sources: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/846938351032713908/

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -i
```

(enter root password)

```
apt-get update   
apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon    
apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati    
apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core    
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup    
rm -rf /etc/ati    
apt-get autoremove steam    
apt-get install steam
```

(agree to user agreement)