# tf2 crash on startup

Tags: steam

I played tf2 this afternoon, like the last 3 month on Ubuntu 12.04 I had no problem. I saw there was an update at 18h52. Now the game crash while still in the splash screen: I dont get to the menus. I updated to the experimental nvidia driver like Steam is recommended. I also followed the advices on this page:

[Black screen on tf2 on ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231966/black-screen-on-tf2-on-ubuntu-12-04)

I can't find a way to get back into the game...

Answer (score 2):

Valve's aware of the issue, and they're working on fixing it.

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3125849